# Burninate the [information] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

There are currently **162** questions tagged [information](/questions/tagged/information). This tag is so general, it's completely meaningless. Information about what, exactly? There is no tag wiki and it appears to be used more or less randomly.

I have checked the questions in this tag, and the other tags on these questions are more than sufficient. Can we burn it?

[image: Trogdor, we need you!]

Comment: So far I've found and cleaned up a bunch of `file`+`information`, `system`+`information` and other such pairs.  Lots of people talking about `information-theory` and `information-extraction` as well.

Answer (score 4):

[information](/questions/tagged/information) has been purged with righteous fire.

I've added it to the list of **95** tags I keep dead every day.

Comment: Come on. You can't tease us like that and not show the other 94.

Comment: I'm actually up to 114 now.  [Here's a list from the other week](http://pastebin.com/rQY0dD6X) when the maximum tags per page was reduced from 50 to 25, requiring a reshuffling of the list.  I'm just a bit of effort away from just writing a StackExchange API application to monitor things for me...